# Printing out a HTML document in C#

Tags: c#, html

Just to be clear I'm not asking you to do the project for me (This is my 2nd time I use C# ever), just for a little help getting started. I have no idea how to get started on this project and textbook/google search haven't got me anywhere.

**Below is a part of the project description. If someone could explain how this works or help me in the search for relevant information it would be greatly appreciated.**

Write a single program called MultiplicationTable, that accepts as input a single integer number in the range 1 - 20, and prints out (using `Console.WriteLine` or `Console.Write`) a HTML document which displays the multiplication table for the input number.

Example of a command line:

```
MultiplicationTable.exe 5 > Result.html
```

should result in a file called `Result.html` being created in the same folder as the .exe file (note: the > syntax will take care of creating the file, all you need to do is to print out the results using Console.WriteLine as stated above). This file should be a valid XHTML file, with a single table in the body of the document:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't actually need to worry about printing anything (other than writing some strings to the console output). The `>` just sends the output of an executable to a file rather than stdout. That means your application just needs to act as though it's trying to write some html as output:

```
Console.WriteLine("<html>");
Console.WriteLine("<head>");
Console.WriteLine("<title>Some Title</title>");
Console.WriteLine("</head>");
Console.WriteLine("<body>");
// Actual multiplication table
Console.WriteLine("</body>");
Console.WriteLine("</html>");
```

Keep in mind though that this example is not valid XHTML (you'll need to figure out for yourself what constitutes a valid XHTML file) nor will it generate your markup for the actual multiplication table. It's simply an example of what the problem wants you to do.

Comment: @Nate - Actually, I would suggest using MDN rather than W3Schools. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XHTML

Comment: Fair enough. That's a fine source too.

Comment: I set up the HTML code with each tag/attribute in console.Writeline. I still don't quite understand how I send the output to this HTML document with MultipicationTable.exe >Result.html.

Comment: @user3265963 - I explained that in my answer. It's a feature of the Windows command line (and Powershell and different Linux shells as well). When you run a command from the command line, you can send the output to a file rather than stdout (which is the screen). You can try it yourself. Open a command line and run `dir /w > directories.log` and then open the resulting `directories.log` file in a text editor.